# Why does path not work as a $variable?

Tags: bash

In my .bash_profile I have this line:

```
export dl="~/Desktop/Diffs/today.diff"
```

I use this file as a throwaway for opening quick diffs now and then through the day in sublime, and I got tired of writing out the path so I tried making it a variable. But it doesn't work.

If I write `git diff HEAD~ > ~/Desktop/diffs/today.diff`, all is well. However, if I try using `git diff HEAD~ > $dl` instead, it tells me:

> -bash: ~/Desktop/Diffs/today.diff: No such file or directory

Why?

Comment: The problem is that `~` expansion happens at the wrong time (see [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) and note that `~` expansion occurs before, not after, variable expansion).  Use `export dl="$HOME/Desktop/Diffs/today.diffs"`.

Comment: FYI, [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) catches common shell script errors [including this one](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2088).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`~`-expansion does not happen inside quotes. You can fix that by putting the `~/` outside the quotes:

```
export dl=~/"Desktop/..."
```

which works even if the path contains spaces.

Lots more info on this over at Unix & Linux: [Why doesn't the tilde (~) expand inside double quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151850/why-doesnt-the-tilde-expand-inside-double-quotes)

Comment: You can also use "$HOME" instead.

Comment: Yes, but that fails if the wanted path was `~someotheruser/Public/...`

Comment: I tried `export dl=~"/Desktop/Diffs/today.diff"` but I got the same error actually. Which is weird because I don't at all disbelieve you that this should work.

Comment: I tried it with `$HOME` and got the same error, too. Except that it expanded out the path all the way to `/com/home/users/myuser/...` I'm on Ubuntu....doubt that would matter but thought I'd mention it at this point...

Comment: Sorry typo, the / also needs to be outside the quotes (misremembered the exact syntax)